# How to fix jquery bug

Tags: jquery

I currently have a jquery bug unsure how to fix it.

I think i may have to many or not enough closing tags?

Any help would  be much appreciated !
Please see code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#main-tab a').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
    })


    // pagination margins 
    var length = $('.pagination li a').length;
    for(var a = 0; a <= length; a++){
        if(a == length-1){
            $('.pagination li:nth-child('+a+')').find('a').addClass('pagi-margin-item1');
        } else if(a == (length-length)+2){
            $('.pagination li:nth-child('+a+')').find('a').addClass('pagi-margin-item2');
        }

    }
    //slider for age of create profile
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 10,
      max: 120,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#age-from" ).val( ui.values[ 0 ]).css('text-align', 'center');
          $( "#age-to" ).val( ui.values[ 1 ]).css('text-align', 'center');
      }
    });
    $( "#age-from" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ));
    $( "#age-to" ).val( $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ));
});


        //table jquery to make the first column look disables and its style
    $('table.table td:first-child').css({'background-color':'rgba(219, 217, 217, 0.36);',
   'color':'rgba(197, 195, 192, 0.76)'});
    $('table td').addClass('table-style');
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're missing a bunch of semi-colons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check the code, I usually go to the http://jsfiddle.net web site, and perform a JSHint action to validate the code. All errors will be highlighted by a red tag.

You could also try this reference web site : http://www.jslint.com/

Try yourself to reproduce the syntax error search with these web site.

Here is the VALID JS code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#main-tab a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).tab('show');
    });


    // pagination margins 
    var length = $('.pagination li a').length;
    for (var a = 0; a <= length; a++) {
        if (a == length - 1) {
            $('.pagination li:nth-child(' + a + ')').find('a').addClass('pagi-margin-item1');
        } else if (a == (length - length) + 2) {
            $('.pagination li:nth-child(' + a + ')').find('a').addClass('pagi-margin-item2');
        }

    }
    //slider for age of create profile
    $("#slider-range").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 10,
        max: 120,
        values: [75, 300],
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#age-from").val(ui.values[0]).css('text-align', 'center');
            $("#age-to").val(ui.values[1]).css('text-align', 'center');
        }
    });
    $("#age-from").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 0));
    $("#age-to").val($("#slider-range").slider("values", 1));
});


//table jquery to make the first column look disables and its style
$('table.table td:first-child').css({
    'background-color': 'rgba(219, 217, 217, 0.36);',
        'color': 'rgba(197, 195, 192, 0.76)'
});
$('table td').addClass('table-style');
```